# Cygwin Terminal - Reading from file

Tags: terminal, cygwin

I'm using the Cygwin Terminal and I'm trying to get input from a file.
I have a file filled with numbers (decimal numbers), a new number is on each line. The file has positive and negative numbers.
The following code can produce positive numbers:

```
  double a[MAX];
    double num;
    int n;
    scanf("%lf", &num);
    while (num >= 0) {
        a[n] = num;
        n++;
        scanf("%lf", &num);
    }
```

However if I try to change '0' to look for numbers below 0, it gives an error.

How can I put negative and positive numbers into the array?

Comment: which error ? This seems a C question not a cygwin one.

Comment: In your code I don't see the inizialization of "n"